# Best JavaScript Design Pattern for labels + graph generation based on select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, jquery-plugins

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and have to generate a graph based on a select drop down.
[image]

Selecting a value from the View drop down will automatically display some labels with respective values (See mock circle 5 and 6) (eg. Power Cap (W) with an Average value of 20 W)

The graph will mainly be  Y VS X, with one Y-axis. However, If 'Custom' is selected from the drop down, an more than one label will appear (ie. instead of peak power alone, I get peak and average power) and there will be at most 2 Y axis (see mock). Selecting anything other than Custom will default back to just one Y axis

The data is fetch over a X hour period.

What is the best recommended design pattern to implement this ?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Comment: [http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax)